# Should I glue the dowels in a self-assembled cabinet kit?

Tags: cabinets

Once again I found my self assembling a cabinet. I am always in the dilemma to glue the wooden pins (on both sides) or not to glue it.

If I do not glue it, the structural holding strength of the wooden pin is minimal to none.

If I do glue it, the hold is very strong and **permanent**, making the metal pins twist lock almost useless.

Once glued there is no going back, so the assembly better be correct. What is the right way ?

[image: wood pin]

Comment: I've had some specify using glue and the glue was provided, others do _not_ specify or provide glue. I've found no difference in apparent structural strength after assembly. Also, the ones I've had that specify glue only show it in the instructions on _one_ side of the dowel. The dowels provide sheer support for horizontal members in addition to line up, sheer support works with or without glue.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. There is no "right" here. Decide whether you value robust construction over future portability and move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not glue.  If glue was needed, it should have been provided with the cabinet and its use included in the assembly instructions.

Also, those dowels are meant to hold/align the pieces perpendicular to the axis of the dowels - that is up and down or left and right in the photo.  They are not to support the wood along the longitudinal axis of the dowel, or to provide resistance from one piece of wood pulling away from the other along the axis of the dowel.

Comment: The glue was always provided in the earlier versions - taken out because it saved pennies and reduced the life so they could sell more.

Comment: @SolarMike Reduce the life, eh? I have 50 year old pieces that have been assembled and reassembled multiple times still in perfectly good shape. Don't think so. If you tighten the camlocks correctly, it doesn't move. And no glue from that "earlier" time.

Comment: @Ecnerwal 99% of the customers don't have our skills... They can often break them the first time they assemble them.

Comment: Although this is entirely a matter of opinion, I wholeheartedly disagree with your opening statement. It's a marketing decision to keep assembly simple. It _will_ result in a better outcome to apply glue regardless of mention in the instructions. I also disagree with the second paragraph. Locking hardware is notoriously prone to loosening and other failures. Dowels in tension would really help.

Answer (score 6):

It's a knockdown cabinet - made to permit it to be made small again for transport or storage.

If you don't care about that, glue away. I have found the ability to disassemble useful. One person can easily carry parts that are too awkward to be moved as a whole, and the parts fit through doorways and hallways and around corners in stairways that might be difficult or impossible to get the assembled object through.

The wooden pins are just for alignment - the camlock metal fasteners do the holding it together.

No glue is mentioned in the instructions because there is no need for glue.

Comment: This. Installed correctly and tightened, the camlocks will hold the cabinet pieces firmly in place.

Comment: Dowels do provide extra sheer support for horizontal members whether glued or not. They also help prevent/reduce sagging for overloaded horizontal members. Overall agree, though, +1